# KSH: Find a human date in a file and convert it to an epoch in place

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ksh

I am new to KSH, and grep,awk,sed, etc.

My task is this:

I am writing a script that goes through keystores, and opens them. I then want to **find the Valid until date, and convert it to epochs**. I can do this either in place, or write **the whole file, including both edited and unedited pieces** to a new file, if that is easier.

My input looks like this:

```
Alias name: mycertname
Creation date: Dec 31, 1969
Entry type: entry type

Owner: owner info
Issuer: issuer info
Serial number: serial number
Valid from: 6/11/03 2:23 PM until: 6/6/23 2:23 PM
Certificate fingerprints: <...>
```

There are many outputs like this in the file.

There is an issue to consider.

1) Not all of these certs seem to have a Valid from line.

I have the established the command that I am planning on using to convert the date to epochs:

```
date +%s -d"string I cut from input"
```

What I am not sure how to do, is format my output.

My ideal output would look like this:

```
Alias name: mycertname     1686075780
```

Or

```
Alias name: mycertname
1686075780
```

Comment: So you're not interested in the rest of the lines in the file - you just want those parts?

Comment: That you use ksh leads me to suspect that you're not on Linux using GNU tools. Can you tell us which version of awk you're using?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.8 is the version of Awk in the environment that I was told to use to write the script. 
The reason we are using KSH, is because we may also need this script on AIX servers as well as Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking along these lines:

```
awk '/^Alias/ { alias = $0 } /^Valid from:/ { sub(/.*until: /, ""); cmd = "date +%s -d \"" $0 "\""; if((cmd | getline epoch) != 1) { epoch = "Broken timestamp" } close(cmd); print alias, epoch }' filename
```

That is:

```
/^Alias/ {                         # When a line begins with "Alias"
  alias = $0                       # remember it
}
/^Valid from:/ {                   # When a line begins with "Valid from:"
  sub(/.*until: /, "")             # Remove everything before the until date
  cmd = "date +%s -d \"" $0 "\""   # build the shell command to execute
  if((cmd | getline epoch) != 1) { # execute it, get its output
    epoch = "Broken timestamp"     # in case of failure, set easily
                                   # recognizable replacement message.
                                   # If you want to skip broken records like
                                   # those without a timestamp, use "next"
                                   # instead.
  }
  close(cmd)                       # close the pipe
  print alias, epoch               # print the remembered alias followed by
                                   # the output of that command.
}
```

Comment: This was spot on. Thank you so much, I never imagined I would get a response so quickly! And thank you so much for your great explanation, as a newbie, you broke it down perfectly for me.
If I had the reputation required to upvote (as my account is new to stackoverflow as well.. haha), I surely would upvote. So please everyone else, upvote this!

Comment: Although, if you wouldn't mind clarifying something for me.
You save $0 into alias, and then you use $0 again to fill in for the date command. Is that a new scope, and that is why you can use $0 again?

And also, how does this line handle the case where there is no valid from line? What happens to those that have an alias name, but no valid from date?

Comment: `$0` is the current line (actually current record, but by default a record is a line). The control flow of awk works so that a record (line) is read, the code is executed for it, the next record is read, the code is executed for it, and so forth. Variables are retained between records. So: The input is read linewise. When a line matches `^Alias`, it is remembered. Since it does not match `^Valid from:`, that block is not run for it. When later a line that matches `^Valid from:` is read, likewise only the second block is executed for it. [Helpful link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: I added this edit while you were typing I think, so you may not have seen it. One last (I think/hope for your sake ) question: 
How does this line handle the case where there is no valid from line? What happens to those that have an alias name, but no valid from date?

Comment: They aren't printed with the current code. It's not hard to patch something in for that, but you'd have to put into the question what you want to happen in those cases.

Comment: That is actually fairly ideal I think. In this situation :
    Alias name: mycertname
    Creation date: Dec 31, 1969

    Alias name: mycertname
Creation date: Dec 31, 1969
    Entry type: entry type
    
    Owner: owner info
    Issuer: issuer info
    Serial number: serial number
Valid from: 6/11/03 2:23 PM until: 6/6/23 2:23 PM
    Certificate fingerprints: <...>

Would it see the first name, look for a valid from line, not find it, so it doesn't print it, then it finds the next alias name, it DOES find a valid from, so it then prints that?

Comment: Exactly so. Whenever a `Valid from:` line is found, the until date is printed with the most recently seen alias line.